# 2D Array rotation in C by 90

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote this code to rotate a square matrix by 90 degrees. but it started to show me runtime error.
I have absolutely no clue why i get that notice.Can someone please fix the code for me.
It shows me segmentation fault.i have no clue what that means.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int N, i = 0, j = 0;
  scanf("%d", &N);
  int A[N][N], B[N][N], temp;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      scanf("%d", (A[i][j]));
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      B[i][j] = A[j][i];
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      temp = B[i][j];
      B[i][j] = B[N - i - 1][j];
      B[N - i - 1][j] = temp;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      printf("%d", B[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: neither have we. use a debugger.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

replace this `scanf("%d",(A[i][j]));` with this `scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);`

Comment: Actually, gcc provides a useful warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
        scanf("%d",(A[i][j]));
        ^